# Cumsum based on date and ID

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a data frame acting as a changelog. I want to cumulatively sum value of the current date and all previous, filtering out the old duplicate ID.

Very similar to this issue:
[cumsum() up to and including current date in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823116/cumsum-up-to-and-including-current-date-in-dplyr)

## Here is the current code:

```
library(dplyr)
tribble(~ID,~Date, ~value,
        "ID-1", "2019-01-01", 50,
        "ID-2", "2019-01-02", 20,
        "ID-3", "2019-01-03", 35,
        "ID-1", "2019-01-04", 0,
        "ID-4", "2019-01-04", 20,
        "ID-5", "2019-01-04", 25,
        "ID-6", "2019-01-07", 100,
        "ID-3", "2019-01-08", 0,
        "ID-7", "2019-01-08", 15,
        "ID-8", "2019-01-08", 10,
        "ID-6", "2019-01-10", 0,
        "ID-9", "2019-01-10", 45,
        "ID-10", "2019-01-10", 40) %>% arrange(Date) %>%  mutate(run_sum=cumsum(value)) %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate(run_sum = last(run_sum))
```

## Outputs:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   Date [7]
   ID    Date       value run_sum
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 ID-1  2019-01-01    50      50
 2 ID-2  2019-01-02    20      70
 3 ID-3  2019-01-03    35     105
 4 ID-1  2019-01-04     0     150
 5 ID-4  2019-01-04    20     150
 6 ID-5  2019-01-04    25     150
 7 ID-6  2019-01-07   100     250
 8 ID-3  2019-01-08     0     275
 9 ID-7  2019-01-08    15     275
10 ID-8  2019-01-08    10     275
11 ID-6  2019-01-10     0     360
12 ID-9  2019-01-10    45     360
13 ID-10 2019-01-10    40     360
```

Any good way to get the run_sum column to look like this?

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
   ID    Date       value run_sum
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 ID-1  2019-01-01    50      50
 2 ID-2  2019-01-02    20      70
 3 ID-3  2019-01-03    35     105
 4 ID-1  2019-01-04     0     100
 5 ID-4  2019-01-04    20     100
 6 ID-5  2019-01-04    25     100
 7 ID-6  2019-01-07   100     200
 8 ID-3  2019-01-08     0     190
 9 ID-7  2019-01-08    15     190
10 ID-8  2019-01-08    10     190
11 ID-6  2019-01-10     0     175
12 ID-9  2019-01-10    45     175
13 ID-10 2019-01-10    40     175
```

Where the run_sum filters out the older ID duplicate value when a new ID update occurs?

Comment: Can you please provide how exactly should it be calculated? Let's say, how is `run_sum` on row 5 calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's one way, first we look at the values by ID and keep track of the the difference from the previous value with `ival`. Then we look again by date, and for each date group, find the total change in value. Then, we keep the change in value only for the first row in that group. Then we can run a cumulative sum on that column to get the value we want.

```
dd %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(ival=value-lag(value,default=0)) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(diff = sum(ival)) %>% 
  mutate(diff = diff * (row_number()==1)) %>% # only keep first
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(run_sum = cumsum(diff)) %>% 
  select(-ival, -diff)

#    ID    Date       value run_sum
#    <chr> <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 ID-1  2019-01-01    50      50
#  2 ID-2  2019-01-02    20      70
#  3 ID-3  2019-01-03    35     105
#  4 ID-1  2019-01-04     0     100
#  5 ID-4  2019-01-04    20     100
#  6 ID-5  2019-01-04    25     100
#  7 ID-6  2019-01-07   100     200
#  8 ID-3  2019-01-08     0     190
#  9 ID-7  2019-01-08    15     190
# 10 ID-8  2019-01-08    10     190
# 11 ID-6  2019-01-10     0     175
# 12 ID-9  2019-01-10    45     175
# 13 ID-10 2019-01-10    40     175
```

This is where `dd` is your data without the `run_sum` value